# Silverlight toolkit breaks silverlight 5 application

Tags: silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I am upgrading a Silverlight 4 application to Silverlight 5.  I ran the application after changing the Target Silverlight Version to Silverlight 5 (Visual Studio 2010) and received the following error before the application loaded:

Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2110
Category: InitializeError
Message: AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR

I was unable to track down the issue using the visual studio debugger so I thought it might be an issue with the references.  I noticed most of the core libraries were now pointing to the Silverlight/v5.0 directories in the Microsoft/Framework directories but the Toolkit libraries were not upgraded.  I downloaded the May 2012 release of the toolkit and manually upgraded all those libraries but still received the error.  So I created a new Silverlight 5 project and began adding the libraries incrementally.  That application then threw that error when I added references to the Silverlight Toolkit.  How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the middle of writing my question I decided to try nuget to install the toolkit and the error has now been resolved.  I am leaving the question because I spent a few hours working on it and there is not much information regarding error code 2110 for Silverlight.  I did notice that nuget installs version 4.0.5.0 of the toolkit libraries and the May 2012 toolkit shows version 5.0.5.0 so that may be the issue.